# Detect duplicate titles using feedparser

Tags: python, feedparser

```
def parseRSS(rss_url):
    parsed_feed = feedparser.parse(rss_url)
    return parsed_feed

def getHeadlines(rss_url,key):
    headlines = []
    feed = parseRSS(rss_url)
    for newsitem in feed['items']:
        if newsitem['title'] not in headlines:
            headlines.append([newsitem,key])
        else:
            print("-----------------------Duplicate title found----------------------")
    return headlines

def get_rss():
    allheadlines = []
    newsurls = {
    ('key1','source1'): 'https://news.google.com/news/rss/?hl=en&amp;ned=us&amp;gl=US',
    ('key2','source2'): 'https://news.google.com/news/rss/?hl=en&amp;ned=us&amp;gl=US',
    }
    for key,url in newsurls.items():
        allheadlines.extend(getHeadlines(url,key))

    return allheadlines

allheadlines = get_rss()

for hl in allheadlines:
    source = hl[1][0]
    key = hl[1][1]
    title = hl[0]['title']
    link = hl[0]['link']
```

I'm using the same rss feed for testing purposes. I'm checking if the title is already in headlines every time I append a new headline. However, it doesn't seem to detect duplicate titles. Duplicate title found is never being printed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you may try print `feed` first, there may not be any duplicate headlines any in the first place.

Comment: I'm using the same rss feed twice in this example to ensure there will be duplicate titles.

Comment: okay, but you never pass the `allheadlines` in, so  `headlines = []` wil lalways make the comparision meaningless

Comment: beacuse u r creating `null list` every time, when you run the loop

Comment: try pass the `allheadlines` in your `getHeadlines` function, if it does not work then come back

Comment: I tried doing as you said, passing allheadlines in getHeadlines function. It still doesn't seem to be detecting duplicate titles.

Comment: how did u do it?

Comment: allheadlines.extend(getHeadlines(url,key,allheadlines) , then getHeadlines(rss_url,key,allheadlines), lastly if newsitem['title'] not in allheadlines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
def parseRSS(rss_url):
    parsed_feed = feedparser.parse(rss_url)
    return parsed_feed

def getHeadlines(rss_url,key,allheadlines,allitems):
    feed = parseRSS(rss_url)
    for newsitem in feed['items']:
        if newsitem['title'] not in allheadlines:
            allheadlines.append(newsitem['title'])
            allitems.append([newsitem,key])
        else:
            print("-----------------------Duplicate title found----------------------")
    return allheadlines,allitems

def get_rss():
    allheadlines = []
    allitems = []
    newsurls = {
    ('key1','source1'): 'https://news.google.com/news/rss/?hl=en&amp;ned=us&amp;gl=US',
    ('key2','source2'): 'https://news.google.com/news/rss/?hl=en&amp;ned=us&amp;gl=US',
    }
    for key,url in newsurls.items():
        allheadlines,allitems=(getHeadlines(url,key,allheadlines,allitems))

    return allitems

allheadlines = get_rss()
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to detect duplicate titles

Comment: That worked however, it changed how my original code worked. I need to extend everything to allheadlines, not just title. I need to access title, link, updated_parsed, key, and source. In this new function, only title's are appended to allheadlines.